# calling method in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Predicts.java

```
public class Predicts {
    public void predict() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Output.java

```
public class Output extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

In a different servlet, how do I initialise a method from Predicts.java and call it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method function from another class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269193/how-to-call-a-method-function-from-another-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object from the Servlet class and call the method:

```
public class Output extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

     Predicts p = new Predicts();
     p.predict();
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

this.predict();

No need to create new instance