# calling a getter method from multiple methods in a different class than the getter

Tags: java, oop

I'm in the process of learning Java and trying to use OOP style programming. The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to call a getter method in one class, for another class, it only works within the method that I create an object in and I'm calling from. My question is: Is it possible to call a getter from multiple methods in a different class than the getter method class? If so, how do I go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is so vague dude... can't really say anything there. Give us concrete questions and concrete programs.

Comment: Show us the minimum amount of code to demonstrate your problem. Real, but minimum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a method function from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269193/how-to-call-a-method-function-from-another-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am not mistake you wanna try call different methods from different classes right?

```
public class A {
    public void getMethodFromClassA(){
       ....
    }
}

public class B {
   public void getMethodFromClassB(){
     ........
   }
}
```

call the method

```
public class C {

    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

   private void methodCaller(){

      a.getMethodFromClassA();
      b.getMethodFromClassB();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Gusti. You're on the right track, but haven't gone quite far enough. I want to call a getter method from a different class, but not from the same method where I create the object. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @DanBennett so do you want to call other other class getter method, but not in the same method where that other class object is created?

Comment: That looks like what I want to do. I'll code it and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Gusti, I think that fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The class with getter method:

```
public class A {
    public void getter(){
       ....
    }
}
```

The class that calls the getter method:

```
public class B {

    A a = new A();

    private void callMethod(){
        a.getter();
    }
}
```

If the class that calls the getter method includes the main method, than make the create a with the `static` keyword: `static A a = new A();`.